# Wordpress Captcha v2 insivisble not working - orange error - js errors

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form-7, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I have contact forms 7 installed with Invisible captcha (By Mihai Chelaru),

Whenever I submit a form I get an orange box error message: "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later."

I tried configuring Contact form 7 with v2 and v3 as well, still get the orange box,

I see errors in the JS output:

```
The script from “https://x.ca/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderInvisibleReCaptcha&render=explicit” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://x.ca/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderInvisibleReCaptcha&render=explicit”. contact:538:1
```

could it be an htaccess issue?

Please help, all input is welcome.

Comment: there are lots of errors coming up in contact form 7 with recaptcha these days. anyways, are you doing it on live site or on localhost?

Comment: On a live site.

Comment: if i am correct, the message "there was error"... its one of contact form's default error message, not recaptcha's error, do you still get it when u use contact form without any recaptcha?

Comment: the orange box error means the captcha thinks its spam, and without captcha the form works fine.

Comment: okay, have you tried using another plugins to see if they produce same type of errors, like try this one with https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-recaptcha/ if possible.

Comment: I will try that plugin later, but shouldn't contact form 7 work with recaptcha out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

If your form is working good without ReCaptcha then an error should be in your ReCaptcha plugin. Because sometimes this happens when ReCaptcha is not working and shows some error. but without ReCaptcha form works well.

You can try another plugin like this. check with this plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-recaptcha/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with Configuration for Contact Form 7 plugin.

I use this one ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7) for all WP sites in my company and it works with reCaptcha V2 and V3.

Hope it can help!